# Inserting a ".01" into database c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to insert "0000.0000.0000.0001" into a varchar(50) in my sql database in c#. I keep getting this error:

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 122,Token in error = .0000 ]

How my insertion looks like is:

```
string version = "0000.0000.0000.0001";
 INSERT INTO [DBFileInfo] (DBFileInfoID,DatabaseType,Version, Description, CreationDate,ReleaseDate) 
values(1,1,"+version.ToString()+
",`Default Beverage DB created by DbGen`,
   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

The initial build of the table is:

```
 string info = " CREATE TABLE [DBFileInfo]( [DBFileInfoID] INT NOT NULL,[DatabaseType] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(-1),[Version] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, [Description] NVARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, [CreationDate] DATETIME,[ReleaseDate] DATETIME);";
```

is there a way around this so I could insert the "." into it without getting an exception?

THanks!

Comment: why not just use the variable `version` in your insert?

Comment: look at your query again and pay attention to the `""` quotations this why in my opinion it's always better to go with Parameterized queries, that way you don't have to muck around with matching up `sing quotes and double quotes`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the string inside single quotes:

```
string version = "0000.0000.0000.0001";
...values(1,1,'" + version + "','...
```

**HOWEVER**

I strongly recommend you use parameters instead. e.g.

```
string version = "0000.0000.0000.0001";
string sql = @"INSERT INTO [DBFileInfo] (DBFileInfoID,DatabaseType,Version, Description, CreationDate,ReleaseDate) 
                VALUES(1,1,@Version,'Default Beverage DB created by DbGen',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Version", version);
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: An observation not related to your question.  version.ToString() is redundant as version is already a string.

Comment: Good point, I merely copied and pasted that out of the question. I've changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you missed quotation marks, try:

```
... values(1,1,'"+version.ToString()+"','Default Beverage ..
```

Though you might be using parameter

```
... values(1,1,@version,'Default Beverage ..
```

in this case you will have to execute your statement with parameter `@version` and pass value to it.